# Docker container ssh not starting if starting a script or settings LD_PRELOAD

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, environment-variables, ld-preload

I have a Docker image which starts SSH at startup and listen for connections:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/deepstream:6.0-triton

# OTHER STUFF HERE 
# ....

# SSH AND REMOTE LOGIN FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:my_password' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
RUN sed -i 's/\(^Port\)/#\1/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config && echo Port 2222 >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Export 2222 for SSH server
EXPOSE 2222

# ENV 
# LD_PRELOAD="/src/libmyplugins.so:${LD_PRELOAD}"

# STARTUP
# Disable previous entrypoint.
ENTRYPOINT []
# Set default dir
WORKDIR /src
# Enable SSH for debug on remote server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

My goal is to be able to add `/src/libmyplugins.so` to `LD_PRELOAD`.
I tried a few things, and all of them resulted in the container stopping right after starting:

- Add `LD_PRELOAD="/src/libmyplugins.so:${LD_PRELOAD}"` to the Dockerfile
- Create a script an `entrypoint.sh` to be run at startup with `CMD ["sh", "entrypoint.sh", "&&", "/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]` with the goal of setting the env variable inside the script file.

Comment: What is not working? You've commented out the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable in your `Dockerfile`. When this is uncommented, is the environment variable visible when you ssh into the container?

Comment: I'd expect sshd to generally reset the environment for login sessions, so if you set an `ENV` in the Dockerfile it might not get reflected for user sessions.  Do you need the ssh daemon, or can you set the container to just run the program in question?

Comment: If I uncomment the line, SSH doesn't start when I start the container. The image terminates. I need SSH because I am using the container as a remote interpreter through PyCharm